# Sharing styles and classes outside of the application while loading the js

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application that displays data in a "ghost' mode while loading APIs. The "ghost" mode is done by using a directive on elements. And is currently only implemented within the application.

I would like to use the same classes / styles from this directive (SCSS) in the main HTML to be used while the application is loading.

Is there a way to export a SCSS file (and some variables) to be inline in the index.html file? Or at least as it's own small CSS file linked in the main HTML.

Basically, I'm trying to re-use styles etc. outside of the Angular application and wondered if there was a way to do this and what the best practice is.

I want to avoid having the same styles in multiple files and I wouldn't expect someone to update the main HTML file if the loading / ghost style changed.

Comment: I've had similar problems in an internship I worked few years ago and I think (that's what my senior dev told me) it's really hard  / near impossible. You can't really link the scss file without it compiling to css, so that would need to be done first. Maybe you could try to modify your run script, so that the `index.scss` (idk if you have something like this) gets compiled, if that's the case, you could (theoretically) link it to the `index.html`. Correct me if I'm wrong but thats the only thing I could think of back then and now.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you need.. but does this help? https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config